# Peculiar use of 'neque'

Tags: vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation

In Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata Pars I, cap. VI it says,

> Quam longa est via Flaminia? Neque ea tam longa est quam via Appia.

I am unsure as to how to translate 'neque' here or rather why it is used here. Intuitively, I would translate the response as, 'It is not as long as the Via Appia.' But then why does it say 'neque' instead of 'non'?

Comment: I remember this sentence but not what came before it. Was there a different comparison that came before these two sentences?

Answer (score 4):

The text goes as follows:

> Brundisium non est prope Romam, sed procul ab Roma: via Appia longa est. Via Latina non tam longa est quam via Appia. Quam longa est via Flaminia? Neque ea tam longa est quam via Appia.

Before we look this up, let's remember that LLPSI is supposed to teach us Latin. What can this sentence possibly mean? We just met the Via Latina, which was not as long as the super-long Via Appia. Now comes the Via Flaminia, and …

- it is *also* not as long
- it is not as long *either*
- it *too* is not as long

Get it?

That is the basic meaning of *neque*: and not, also not.

Comment: A nice object lesson in the importance of context. Once the preceding sentences are provided, what seemed like a bizarre use of neque suddenly makes total sense.